# Earth Engine Code Editor - Dark Mode

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am new to Google Earth Engine and was messing around with the settings but did not find an option to switch the code editor to dark mode. I did a Google search and found a switch to dark mode for Google devtools but I don't believe that it applies to Earth Engine code editor. I also looked for a dark mode stylus on github and couldn't find one for Earth Engine. Does anyone know a simple way to switch to dark mode, or has a stylus I could use?

[image: This... but like the cool kid's version.]

Comment: Hi, here you can find a great solution [link](https://github.com/joaosiqueira/dark-mode-gee)